# Postgres 9.6 replication from production to custom slave

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave, barman

I have a problem. Currently I have a 1 TB Postgres 9.6 database which is backed up with Barman with streaming.

**What I need:**

**A replication from the production/master to the slave server:**

- On which I can write, I don’t care if the written data on the replica
  is not sent to the master server
- Which can be configured almost in real time or with little delay
- On which I can use dump without locking the master database

As said above I am using Barman for backing up. However I am not able to find out how I can build a replica from Barman which is sync by the master. It was set up by a someone else and i'm not sure its the right solution for what I need.

**My questions:**

- Is Barman the good tool for what I want ?
- If no. Which tools would you suggest to me ?
- If yes. Do you know    how to build replica from    Barman which is
  sync by the master ?    Could you please explain to me    how to do
  it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in master-slave mode, you can't write on slave
if you want to write on replica to you should probably use something like [this](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/bdr/)

also you can make sure all of your writes on master also written on replica via [synchronous-wal-streaming feature](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.3/#synchronous-wal-streaming)
via this feature, before wiritng on master , first master makes sure write was written successfully on replica

except for writing on slave part , barman looks a fit tool for you
writing on slave is a uncommon thing in postgresql